# NullPointerException in android,maybe a database issue

Tags: java, android

here's the code(Where I think the NullPointerException is generated):

```
public String getData(String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4){

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String columns[] = new String[]{"alphabet","st1","st2","st3","st4" };
        Cursor c = db.query("capitals", columns, null, null,null,null, null);
        String result = "";

        int calpha = c.getColumnIndex("alphabet");
        int cst1 = c.getColumnIndex("st1");
        int cst2 = c.getColumnIndex("st2");
        int cst3 = c.getColumnIndex("st3");
        int cst4 = c.getColumnIndex("st4");

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

            if(c.getString(cst1).equals(s1) && c.getString(cst2).equals(s2) && c.getString(cst3).equals(s3) && c.getString(cst4).equals(s4))
                result = c.getString(calpha);
            else
                result = null;

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Log content:

```
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at learn.myandroidapp.hr.HandwritingRecognitionCanvas.getData(HandwritingRecognitionCanvas.java:213)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at learn.myandroidapp.hr.HandwritingRecognitionCanvas$1.onClick(HandwritingRecognitionCanvas.java:103)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-19 21:27:34.263: E/AndroidRuntime(26498):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 21:27:36.604: I/Process(26498): Sending signal. PID: 26498 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `if(c.getString(cst1).equals(s1) && c.getString(cst2).equals(s2) && c.getString(cst3).equals(s3) && c.getString(cst4).equals(s4))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- One of the four strings being passed in is `null`. Check the strings being passed in, right at the start of the method.

or

- One of the strings being pulled from the database is `null`. And add some logging to see if any of the strings from the DB are `null`.

If you want two `null` strings to be regarded as equal, then you need to expand your comparison as follows:

```
if ((s1 == null && c.isNull(cst1)) || 
    (s1 != null && !c.isNull(cst1) && s1.equals(c.getString(cst1)))
    ... repeat for the other three string-pairs       
   )
```

Comment: Actually, one of my database entries is also null, and one of the Strings passed is also null. What should I do? Should I change the entries to " " ?

Answer (score 1):

The String comparisons could throw NullPointerExceptions if the field in the database contains NULL as value. If your arguments s1 to s4 are never null you can turn the equals statement round:

```
s1.equals(c.getString(cst1))
```

In order to avoid NullPointerExceptions completely you can first check for null value:

```
boolean isEqual(String a, String b) {
    return ((a == null && b == null) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

With this code both Strings can be null without an exception being thrown

Comment: Actually, one of my database entries is also null, and one of the Strings passed is also null. What should I do? Should I change the entries to " " ?

Comment: You can use my second code snippet. Instead of calling equals(), use the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly NullPointerException cannot be identify at compile time. This is runtime exception you should debug your program and try to find out whether reference variable contain any value or not(Null). If code try to access this null object for any property then nullpointerexception will raise.